# For BottomNavigation the selected Item is not highlighted in android

Tags: android, android-bottomnav

I have bottomNavigation in my android app as shown below in picture. It works fine if I just click on `home`, `cart` and other bottomNavigation Items.

As you can see in picture that user can navigate to `all categories` in `home`. If I navigate to `AllCategoriesFragment` then in `home` item will be selected in bottomNavigation which is correct behavior. But if I go to `cart` and then click again on `home` then it shows `AllCategoriesFragment` which is also correct behavior but in BottomNavigation it doesnt highlight the `home` items, instead it keep `cart` item highlighted.

How I can get rid of this issue? Or how I can highlight the bottomNavigation selected item programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it programmatically like by getting activity reference inside fragment andd then getting navView from it and afterwards set the check state of the item to true

```
activity?.let {
            val navView = it.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
            navView.menu.getItem(0).setChecked(true)
        }
```